# Rendering a nested object state

Tags: reactjs, jsx

This problem is giving me a huge headache so any help is welcome :)

In this component, I'm making 2 axios calls to different APIs: one for freegeoip and one for openweathermap. I'm storing the data in the `currentCity` state, which is an object with 2 keys, `location` and `weather`. The idea is that the app detects your current location (using freegeoip) and renders location name and weather data (using openweathermap).

I'm positive it's storing the state properly as console logs have confirmed. I can render the location data for currentCity state, but can't seem to render the weather data for currentCity state.

```
  renderCurrentCity(city) {
    console.log('state3:', this.state.currentCity);
    console.log([city.weather.main]);
    return(
      <div>
        <li>{city.location.city}, {city.location.country_name}</li>  // Working
        <li>{city.weather.main.temp}</li>       // Not working
      </div>

    )
  }
```

The console error I get:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null
```

currentCity.location JSON:

```
{
"ip": // hidden,
"country_code": "FR",
"country_name": "France",
"region_code": "GES",
"region_name": "Grand-Est",
"city": "Reims",
"zip_code": "",
"time_zone": "Europe/Paris",
"latitude": 49.25,
"longitude": 4.0333,
"metro_code": 0
}
```

currentCity.weather JSON:

```
{
"coord": {
"lon": 4.03,
"lat": 49.25
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 800,
"main": "Clear",
"description": "clear sky",
"icon": "01d"
}
],
"base": "stations",
"main": {
"temp": 283.15,
"pressure": 1011,
"humidity": 43,
"temp_min": 283.15,
"temp_max": 283.15
},
"visibility": 10000,
"wind": {
"speed": 3.1,
"deg": 350
},
"clouds": {
"all": 0
},
"dt": 1493127000,
"sys": {
"type": 1,
"id": 5604,
"message": 0.1534,
"country": "FR",
"sunrise": 1493094714,
"sunset": 1493146351
},
"id": 2984114,
"name": "Reims",
"cod": 200
}
```

Rest of code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import WeatherList from './weatherlist';
import SearchBar from './searchbar';

const API_KEY = '95108d63b7f0cf597d80c6d17c8010e0';
const ROOT_URL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?'


export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cities: [],
      errors: '',
      currentCity: {
        location: {},
        weather: {}
      }
    };
    this.currentCity();
    this.renderCurrentCity = this.renderCurrentCity.bind(this);
  }

  citySearch(city) {

    const url = `${ROOT_URL}&appid=${API_KEY}&q=${city}`;

    axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {

      const citiesArr = this.state.cities.slice();
      this.setState({
        cities: [response.data, ...citiesArr],
        errors: null
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.setState({
        errors: 'City not found'
      })
    })
  }

  currentCity() {
    var city;
    var country;

    axios.get('http://freegeoip.net/json/')
    .then(response => {
      const lat = response.data.latitude;
      const lon = response.data.longitude;
      city = response.data.city;
      country = response.data.country_name;

      const url = `${ROOT_URL}&appid=${API_KEY}&lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}`;

      const state = this.state.currentCity;
      console.log('state1:',state);
      this.setState({
        currentCity: { ...state, location: response.data }
      });
      console.log(url);
      axios.get(url)
      .then(city => {

        const state = this.state.currentCity;
        console.log('state2:', state);
        this.setState({
          currentCity: { ...state, weather: city.data }
        });
      })
    })
  }

  renderCurrentCity(city) {
    console.log('state3:', this.state.currentCity);
    console.log([city.weather.main]);
    return(
      <div>
        <li>{city.location.city}, {city.location.country_name}</li>
        <li>{city.weather.main.temp}</li>
      </div>

    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.state.cities == false ? 'search': 'search-up'}>
        <h1>What's the weather today?</h1>
        <ul className='list-unstyled text-center'>
          {this.renderCurrentCity(this.state.currentCity)}
        </ul>
        <SearchBar
          onSearchSubmit={this.citySearch.bind(this)}
          errors={this.state.errors} />
        {this.state.cities == false ? null : <WeatherList cities={this.state.cities} />}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: please share what the console.log output from `renderCurrentCity`

Comment: how do i do that? I can only get the whole console output

Answer (score 0):

You are spreading your whole state when your receive the weather data:

```
this.setState({
    currentCity: { ...state, weather: city.data }
});
```

it should be:

```
this.setState({
    currentCity: { ...state.currentCity, weather: city.data }
});
```

Comment: Still not working... plus, I declare `const state = this.state.currentCity;` prior to adding the weather data to ensure I'm only spreading the currentCity state